# Flutter - How to safely change theme after awaiting theme data from an API in a Widget?

Tags: flutter, widget, themes, flutter-provider, stream-builder

Using a normal setup for handling Theme with a ChangeNotifier that notifies the whole app / everything below it in the three - that something should be redrawn.

This approach seems general and there's multiple "guides" doing it this way. And this works works well when clicking a Button to change it. However, if the data for a Theme is coming from an API - where can we safely update the same value before rendering a Widget?

This is an example code where the ThemeData is somehow "downloaded" and supposed to be updated before rendering the view once the StreamBuilder is done. This, of course, causes the same Widget that's downloading something being redrawn while building so I'm getting a warning for that.

How can this be solved? The Theme can just be a single color that is downloaded and changed dynamically. And so far I haven't seen themes being changed inside one single widget while the "main one" is unchanged. Not sure what's the best approach to this (or similiar) issue - since it can't be uncommon in an mostly online based world.

**Edit #1:** Just to clarify - the Theme might change depending on the Widget / Page / Screen being loaded and it's not a "one time thing" where you initialize it at the beginning but with each screen being loaded - to customize that particular page based on online API data.

Example code:

```
void main() {
    
    runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ThemeConfig(),
        child: MyApp()
    ));

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
        return Consumer<ThemeConfig>(builder: (context, state, child)
        {
            return MaterialApp(
                theme: state.getTheme()
            )
        });
    }
}

class _MyScreen extends State<MyScreen>
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: Api.downloadTheme(),
            builder: (context, snapshot)
            {
                // If OK render screen - But where to safely set the "Theme" from API?

                return MyWidget(context.data)
            });
        )
    }
}

class _MyWidget extends State<MyWidget>
{
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        // This will cause the Widget tree to be redrawn while it's drawing and not work at all
        // So when I've downloaded the data - where can this safely be changed?
        Provider.of<ThemeConfig>(context).setTheme(widget.data.theme);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you wander how to update the theme by fetching if from an api, here is the example of simulating an api call which updates the theme:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      lazy: false, // triggering ThemeConfig constructor
      create: (context) => ThemeConfig(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeConfig>(builder: (context, state, child) {
      return MaterialApp(
        theme: state.theme,
        home: MyScreen(),
      );
    });
  }
}

class ThemeConfig with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeConfig() {
    // trigger theme fetch
    getTheme();
  }

  ThemeData theme = ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue); // initial theme

  Future<void> getTheme() async {
    // TODO: fetch your theme data here and then update it like below
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)); // simulating waiting for response
    theme = ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(), // notice how the colors change
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But the Theme might change depending on the page you load and it's not ever the same. So, the problem is to dynamically load the Theme before showing a certain Widget / Page from an API. Redrawing the whole app so to speak before building the Widget. It's not rocket science and it's also 2022 - I'm guessing it's not that far fetched to achieve. Just not sure of the approach. If the Material App was inside each widget perhaps it'd be easier but it's not at the moment.